# Как получить изображение из инстаграма?

Tags: php, instagram-api

Пожалуйста, приведите пример, как на PHP получить изображение из поста в Instagram с помощью Instagram API.

Comment: Посмотрите [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
function instagram_api_connect( $link ){
    $c_connect = curl_init(); // инициализируем соединение
    curl_setopt($c_connect, CURLOPT_URL, $link); // к этому URL будем подключаться
    curl_setopt($c_connect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($c_connect, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); 
    $json_result = curl_exec($c_connect); // подключаемся, получаем данные
    curl_close($c_connect); // закрываем соединение
    return json_decode( $json_result ); // декодируем из json и возвращаем результат
}
```

Вывод по ИД пользователя

```
$access = 'ваш токен';
$user_id = '1362124742'; 
$result = instagram_api_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/" . $user_id . "/media/recent?access_token=" . $access);

foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    echo '<a id="insta-' . $post->id . '" href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" class="fancybox ' . $post->filter . '"><img src="' . $post->images->thumbnail->url . '" /></a>';
}
```

Вывод по хэштегу

```
$access = 'укажите ваш токен';
$metka = 'hashtag'; // ваш хэштег
$result = instagram_api_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" . $metka . "/media/recent?access_token=" . $access);

//print_r( $result );
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    echo '<a id="insta-' . $post->id . '" href="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '" class="fancybox ' . $post->filter . '"><img src="' . $post->images->thumbnail->url . '" /></a>';
}
```

Это два простых примера. Для более подробной информации изучаем документацию к API [это здесь](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)